# Mongodb db crahes or stops working without any logs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using Mongodb3.2.0 and runs smoothly for long time.But suddenly my Mongo db stops working and I cannot able to see any logs. The only logs I am seeing is like below.I can able to see many logs like this.

```
2016-09-30T05:30:18.963+0000 I QUERY    [conn4] getmore test.abc.users cursorid:1774512014416 ntoreturn:0 exhaust:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:172 nreturned:22082 reslen:4194376 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 346 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 173 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 173 } } } 160ms
```

Comment: come to the end of the log file at the time of crash, and add those logs in the above question.

Answer (score -1):

This output only signifies your program was performing queries.

```
Format:
```

- Timestamp
- Log level : I is for Informational
- Component : Query- Messages related to queries, including query planner activities.

Please refer to [Log documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/).

In order to analyze why mongo process stopped working we would need more information.

Comment: I am not able to find any error logs in mongodb. Will it be the case where the mongodb went inaccessible due to multiple write operation at a time for long time.